# PHPMailer how to bulk email via array id

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, phpmailer

As the title suggests, how do I bulk email using PHPMailer? I have a code where when a user clicks on a specific button in a table, the person is emailed via their email (through select query). Now I have this code wherein when a user selects multiple data in a datatable, a query would run and update the data of all the items selected. I then now copied the code from my working emailer to the looping query (which is nested due to conditions), unfortunately, the emailing part is not working but the query is working. What seems to be the problem with this?

**Includes**

```
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/db.php');
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/phpmailer/src/Exception.php');
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

**Nested Code**

```
else if ($category=="pend")
{
        if ($val==1){
            foreach ($all_id as $value) {
                $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_person where app_id='$value' and app_status='2';"); 
                while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $email = $row["app_email"];
                    $name = $row["app_fname"]." " . $row["app_mname"].". ".$row["app_lname"]; 
                }
                $update = "Update tbl_person set app_status=3 WHERE app_id='$value'";
                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

                $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
                $mail->Port       = 587;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                $mail->Username = 'useremail'; //sample
                $mail->Password = 'emailpassword'; //sample
                $mail->SetFrom('useremail', 'username'); //sample
                $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
                $mail->IsHTML(true);

                $mail->Subject = 'Application Status';
                $mail->Body    = 'Message Body Here';
                $mail->AltBody = 'Message Alt Body Here';
                if (mysqli_query($db,$update)) 
                {
                    header('location:../application.php');
                }
            }
        }
        else if ($val==2){
            foreach ($all_id as $value) {
                $update = "Update tbl_person set app_status=4 WHERE app_id='$value'";
                if (mysqli_query($db,$update)) {
                    header('location:../application.php');
            }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong";
        }
}
```

I have tried moving the mailing code inside and before the `if condition for query` as well as removing the main query to check whether it is working but it ain't. I suspect that the select query is not working just like in the other code unfortunately I can't figure a way to check whether this is true or not. This is the same code I have used for my single button approach that is working. When I try to incorporate it to my loop, the email is not working anymore

Comment: Issuing a Location header from _inside_ a loop, makes rather little sense.

Comment: Hi. Sorry. I am still a student learning this stuff. Should I remove it?

Comment: You are overwriting $email and $name in each iteration of your while loop there, and then you send _one_ email with the values for the last record you selected, after that loop. Sending of the mail obviously belongs _into_ that loop, if you want to send one email for each record it iterates over.

Comment: Yes sir. The concept is kinda like that. The email is stored in a database that's why I placed it inside the loop. I was thinking that `$email` and `$name` will be overwritten as soon as the query takes effect. Unfortunately, only the query has been affected and not the email sending.

Comment: The code for sending the email must be inside the loop as well.

Comment: I recommend basing your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I was able to solve the problem by simply putting the emails to an array and later on tried doing foreach in the mail.

**Code for the Array**

```
$email = array();
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_person where app_id='$value' and app_status='2';"); 
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $email[] = $row["app_email"];
}
```

**Code for the mailer**

```
foreach ($email as $email1) {
$mail->addAddress($email1);
$mail->Subject = 'Test Email';
$mail->Body = 'Hello, this is a test email.';
  
  // Send the email
  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error sending email to ' . $email1 . ': ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
  } else {
    echo 'Email sent to ' . $email1 . '<br>';
  }

// Clear all addresses for the next iteration
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
}
```